# MYSQL MyTAP issue

Tags: mysql, unit-testing

My question may be stupid but I have a 2 days experience in MYSQL. I'm trying to use MyTAP for unit testing and face a problem .

here's the  SQL code exucted on a mysql console:

```
drop procedure  IF EXISTS tap.tstTableCount;
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE tap.tstTableCount (IN db CHAR(64), IN tbl CHAR(64))
  BEGIN
    DECLARE l_sql VARCHAR (4000);
    SET l_sql=CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*)>0 FROM ',db,'.',tbl,';');

    SET @sql=l_sql;
    PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE s1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;

  END //

delimiter ;

call tap.tstTableCount('storibo','relationCategory'); /* This call works fine and returns 1 (true)*/

SELECT tap.ok( 
    tap.tstTableCount('storibo','relationCategory'), 
    'relationCategory contains data' 
); /* this one returns :
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION tap.tstTableCount does not exist */
```

is it an issue with the MyTAP fmk or  do I make a mistake in my syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `tap.tstTableCount` is a `PROCEDURE` and not a `FUNCTION`. All the MyTAP tests are are FUNCTIONS, as noted by being able to call it in a `SELECT` statement. You cannot call a `PROCEDURE` from a `SELECT` statement, instead needing to call it via:

```
CALL tap.tstTableCount();
```

Unfortunately, your example is one that cannot simply be converted to a `FUNCTION` to be used by the mytap functions. Dynamic SQL is not permitted in `FUNCTION`, but is allowed in `PROCEDURE`.